# Custom Spring Bean Parameters

Tags: java, spring, akka

I'm using the Spring Akka example posted on activator to create Spring managed bean actors. This is the code I'm currently using including a demo class:

```
@Component
class Test extends UntypedActor {

    @Autowired
    protected ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    protected final Account account;
    protected final Order order;

    public Test(Account account, Order order) {
        this.account = account;
        this.order = order;
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Object message) throws Exception {
        if (message instanceof SomeCommand) {
            // Do something using the order and the account;
        } else if (message instanceof FooCommand) {
            // More stuff
        }
    }
}

@Component
public class SpringExtension extends AbstractExtensionId<SpringExtensionImpl> implements ExtensionIdProvider {

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Override
    public SpringExtensionImpl createExtension(ExtendedActorSystem system) {
        return applicationContext.getBean(SpringExtensionImpl.class);
    }

    @Override
    public ExtensionId<? extends Extension> lookup() {
        return applicationContext.getBean(SpringExtension.class);
    }

}

@Component
public class SpringExtensionImpl implements Extension {

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    public Props props(String actorBeanName) {
        return Props.create(SpringActorProducer.class, applicationContext, actorBeanName);
    }

}

public class SpringActorProducer implements IndirectActorProducer {

    private final ApplicationContext applicationContext;
    private final String actorBeanName;

    public SpringActorProducer(ApplicationContext applicationContext, String actorBeanName) {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
        this.actorBeanName = actorBeanName;
    }

    @Override
    public Actor produce() {
        return (Actor) applicationContext.getBean(actorBeanName);
    }

    @Override
    public Class<? extends Actor> actorClass() {
        return (Class<? extends Actor>) applicationContext.getType(actorBeanName);
    }

}
```

Now my question is, how do instantiate an actor with custom constructor arguments. I have thought about using a factory or setter methods but I don't think this is an option since the underlying Actor class is not accessible I believe. Any input on this matter is greatly appreciated. If something is now clear, please post a comment.

PS. If you believe my there is an error in my code or there is a better way of going about it, please do tell me! I have little experience with Spring and Akka combined so any advice is appreciated.

Comment: My first comment is that your UntypedActor class should have the @Scope("prototype") annotation as well a @Component. This required because every time you request the Spring extension to create an actor of this type you want it to generate a new instance. The singleton bean concept does not apply here.

Comment: To answer your question, from experience it is not possible to mix approaches to creating you actor. Either all dependencies need to be injected via Spring, or none at all and simply use constructor injection in the standard Akka way using Props. Taking your example above, if Account and Order and spring beans then you can inject them in the same way as you have for the ObjectMapper. Alternatively add the ObjectMapper to your constructor arguments and inject it that way without using Spring when creating a new instance of this actor.

Comment: Just to add, if your Account and Order instances are Spring beans, then you should be able to add the @Autowired annotation to the constructor for them to be injected also.

Comment: They are not spring beans. They are obtained using an ORM framework.

Comment: In this instance then I think you're stuck with a non-Spring approach to creating instances of your Test actor. You will need to add ObjectMapper to the constructor params and inject it that way using Akka Props.

Comment: And if you're ignoring the whole fact that Akka is present? How would I go about creating beans with custom constructors then?

Comment: You either let Spring handle your dependency injection (DI), or you inject the dependencies yourself. If you have a class defined and create a new instance of it via it's constructor in the standard Java way i.e. using the "new" keyword then you have by-passed Spring and therefore by-passed it's DI capabilities.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could pass the additional arguments as varargs (`Object...`) to `SpringExtensionImpl` and `SpringActorProducer`. So your code would look like this:

```
@Component
public class SpringExtensionImpl implements Extension {

   @Autowired
   private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

   public Props props(String actorBeanName, Object... args) {
       return (args != null && args.length > 0) ?
            Props.create(SpringActorProducer.class,
                    applicationContext,
                    actorBeanName, args) :
            Props.create(SpringActorProducer.class,
                    applicationContext,
                    actorBeanName);
    }
}

public class SpringActorProducer implements IndirectActorProducer {

    private final ApplicationContext applicationContext;
    private final String actorBeanName;
    private final Object[] args;

    public SpringActorProducer(ApplicationContext applicationContext, String actorBeanName) {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
        this.actorBeanName = actorBeanName;
        this.args = null;
    }

    public SpringActorProducer(ApplicationContext applicationContext, String actorBeanName, Object... args) {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
        this.actorBeanName = actorBeanName;
        this.args = args;
    }

    @Override
    public Actor produce() {
        return args == null ? 
              (Actor) applicationContext.getBean(actorBeanName):
              (Actor) applicationContext.getBean(actorBeanName, args);
    }

    @Override
    public Class<? extends Actor> actorClass() {
        return (Class<? extends Actor>) applicationContext.getType(actorBeanName);
    }

}
```

You can then create your Test actor like this:

`SpringExtensionImpl springExtensionImpl;
actorSystem.actorOf(springExtensionImpl.create(Test.class, account, order));`

Comment: Keep in mind SpringExtensionImpl in that line to create the actor would be the actual object, not the class name since the class is not static.